# Is there a way to call up a variable of a PHP file running through exec command?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, exec

I ran into a small problem that I'd like to deal with, but still haven't found a solution yet.

I'm making a specific WordPress/WooCommerce plugin that makes adjustments to prices based on the price groups (aka "if this product costs from 1 to 5 dollars, then the adjustment in price is X percent").

*This may be important for understanding - my code makes changes directly to the WooCommerce database, bypassing the function WC supplies to modify the data. I know it's not the recommended way, but I work with massive amounts of records, processing them one by one would take forever.*

The main file woocommerce-functions.php has several functions that are not too resource-intensive.

```
class WC_Price_Manager_WC {
    private $ranges;
    private $current_group_name;
    private $current_range_is_on;
    private $current_range_min;
    private $current_range_max;
    private $current_range_discount;
    private $current_range_price_increase;
    private $products_array = array();
    private $processed_products = array();
    private $limit_per_request;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ranges = $this->getPriceGroups();
        $this->limit_per_request = 2500;

    }

    public function startAction() {
        if ( is_array($this->ranges) && !empty($this->ranges) ) {
            global $wpdb;

            $this->saveGroupsToDB();
            $scanResults = $this->scanDBProducts();
            
            $total_rows = $scanResults[0];
            $cycles_required = $scanResults[1];
            $products_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wcpm_products';
            $wc_posts_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
            $wc_postmeta_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
            
            foreach ($this->ranges as $range) {
                $ranges .= $range[1].','.$range[3].','.$range[4].','.$range[5].','.$range[6].'/';
            }
            
            exec('php ' . $this->root_folder . '/db-worker-plugin.php ' . $cycles_required . ' ' . $ranges . ' ' . $products_table_name . ' ' .  $wc_posts_name . ' ' .  $wc_postmeta_name . ' ' . $this->limit_per_request . ' > ' . $this->root_folder . '/log.txt ' , $output1);
            var_dump($output);
            exit();
        }
    }

    private function getPriceGroups() {
    // Get prices from the admin panel and pushes them into the ranges array
    }

    private function saveGroupsToDB() {
    // Saves the groups in plugin's table in the database for easier accounting
    }

    public function scanDBProducts() {
    // This function determines the overall quantity of products and decides how many passes will be needed to get everything updated
    }
}
```

The worker file does all the heavy lifting - processes the data. It receives the data via the argv, queries the database for the products records which have the necessary prices, determines the new prices and updates them. Here's some of the structure:

```
function executeQuery($cycles_required, $start_number, $limit) {
// Querying the database
}

function rangeChecker($number, $min, $max, $inclusive = false) {
// Checks if the new price matches any of the ranges
}

function groupsDistributionHandler($products_array) {
// Handles the price updates itself, calls the necessary functions
}

function groupDeterminationHandler($product_price) {
// Determines the group for the specific product and returns it as an array, is called when the product gets the new price
}

function calculateApplyPriceIncrease($product_id, $product_price, $price_increase) {
// Calculates the new price based on the price increase and returns it to the distribution handler
}

function batchUpdateDB($array) {
// Creates and executes the update SQL query to the plugin internal table
}

function batchUpdateWC($array) {
// Creates and executes the update SQL query to the WooCommerce table
}
```

There are plenty of other functions but they're mostly for a manual product editing. There's one that's responsible for reverting the prices to the values they were (enable/disable each group).

I did it this way because the script that is called works with a database with a big amount of rows to process. I needed to get rid of the execution time limit. But I also need to track the progress with periodic AJAX calls.

Naturally I made a variable which meant to be continuously updated and a function to retrieve this variable... but can't figure out how to make it work.

So, is it possible to call up a function inside of the script run by exec() while it's running?

I googled this problem but I mostly ran into the "how to pass the arguments" question. Tried the global functions - nope. I read somewhere that scripts that are called with exec() can't access the variables the way I'm trying to do it right now. But I need to pass the data both in and out of the exec-called script as it executes. A direct AJAX call to the file won't do anything, of course, because of the lack of arguments.

Sorry if I'm clumsy or sound like a newbie - not much experience in this.

Comment: `the way I'm trying to do it right now`....which we can't see. (Have a look at [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue)

Comment: `But I need to pass the data both in and out of the exec-called script as it executes`...you'll have to put the status in some shared location where it can be accessed by both processes. Or maybe use a 2-way message queue of some sort

Comment: If the first script is going to be processing the results of the second script, then it will still run into the execution time limit since it has to wait for the second script to produce those results.

Comment: Since you also want to update the UI about progress by the sounds of it, I wonder if websockets might actually work well here. Agree that the first, HTTP-initiated process will need to end in a timely manner. Your long-running job is probably better done as a daemon which is always executing and just waits for (or polls for, depending on the delivery method) some notification which tells it to process a specific task or piece of data. Equally, a regularly-triggered cron job could achieve the same thing. It could then communicate with the client-side and other processes via websocket messages

Comment: I think basically what we're saying is: stop worrying about the globals or passing variables via exec - that's an XY problem, because actually the whole architecture of this is wrong to begin with.

Comment: @barmar - no, the idea is straightly the opposite - send the required parameters to the second file and let the first one end. 
If possible, I want to query this second file directly. But it's more complicated than that, I assume - I need the AJAX to query that second file that is executing, but from what I saw in the output log it appears to create a new instance.

Comment: @ADyson - I've updated the post, hope it clarifies most questions.

Comment: The second script should update a database as it's processing. Then other AJAX requests can query the DB.

Comment: Barmar's suggestion is the simplest way to do it probably. Websockets or another message queuing system gives a bit more flexibility in certain scenarios. And running as a background job is likely more reliable and debuggable than anything via exec()

Comment: P.S. `from what I saw in the output log it appears to create a new instance`...yes that's how HTTP and web applications works. If you make a new request, it executes a new instance of the requested script. Otherwise it would be impossible to have a website accessed by multiple users at once.